# regex replace all ignore case

Tags: java, regex

How do I ignore case in the below example?

```
outText = inText.replaceAll(word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
```

Example:

**Input:**

```
inText = "Retail banking Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Retail banking "
       + "From Wikipedia. retail banking industry."

word   = "retail banking"
```

**Output**

```
outText = "Retail~banking Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Retail~banking " +
          "From Wikipedia. retail~banking industry."
```

Comment: I don't get why case is an issue when replacing space characters.

Comment: oh, because the space has to be between certain case-insensitive matches. If there's no icase option in your language, back refs could do this.

Answer (score 23):

To do case-insensitive search and replace, you can change

```
outText = inText.replaceAll(word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
```

into

```
outText = inText.replaceAll("(?i)" + word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
```

---

### Avoid ruining the original capitalization:

In the above approach however, you're ruining the capitalization of the replaced word. Here is a better suggestion:

```
String inText="Sony Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. " +
              "The company sony ericsson was found in oct 2001";
String word = "sony ericsson";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inText);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
  String replacement = m.group().replace(' ', '~');
  m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String outText = sb.toString();

System.out.println(outText);
```

**Output:**

```
Sony~Ericsson is a leading company in mobile.
The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

Comment: Do note that without the `UNICODE_CASE` or `(?u)` flag that you will not get proper Unicode casefolding.  This doesn’t matter on purely ASCII data, but will if you have non-ASCII casing letters, including just Latin ones like Roman numerals, like `king henry ⅷ` and `King Henry Ⅷ`, which are case variants of each other. An easy non-Latin example is that `ΣΤΙΓΜΑΣ`, `στιγμας`, and `στιγμασ` should all match each other case insensitively because a Greek sigma has three different forms. (And yes, I know the plural of `στιγμα` is really `στιγματα`. :)

Comment: @tchrist are you proposing to replace "(?i)[..]" with "(?ui)[..]"? Thats what worked for me.

Comment: @k3b Yeah that’s what I meant.

Comment: @tchrist you're just save my time, thank you! It's weird that by default unicode casefolding doesn't work out of box

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it all to lowercase before doing the search, or look at a regex modifier Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of doing it:

```
        private String replaceAllIgnoreCase(final String text, final String search, final String replacement){
        if(search.equals(replacement)) return text;
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(text);
        final String lowerSearch = search.toLowerCase(Locale.CANADA);
        int i = 0;
        int prev = 0;
        while((i = buffer.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.CANADA).indexOf(lowerSearch, prev)) > -1){
            buffer.replace(i, i+search.length(), replacement);
            prev = i+replacement.length();
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

Seems to work flawlessly up to my extent. The good thing about doing it my way is that there is no regex in my solution, meaning if you wanted to replace a bracket or a plus sign (or any other meta character for that matter) it will actually replace the text for what it actually is, rather than what it means in regex. Hope this has helped.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language.

Java has Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

C# and VB have RegexOptions.IgnoreCase