# replace words using regex

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regex replace all ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568081/regex-replace-all-ignore-case)

I need to replace all occurrences of Sony Ericsson with a tilda in between them. This is what I have tried

```
String outText="";
    String inText="Sony Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. The company sony ericsson was found in oct 2001";
    String word = "sony ericsson";
    outText = inText.replaceAll(word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
    System.out.println(outText);
```

The output of this is

```
Sony Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

But what I want is

```
Sony~Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

It should ignore cases & give the desired output.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568081/regex-replace-all-ignore-case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
outText = inText.replaceAll("(?i)" + word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
```

to make the search / replace case insensitive.

```
String outText="";
String inText="Sony Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. " +
              "The company sony ericsson was found in oct 2001";
String word = "sony ericsson";
outText = inText.replaceAll("(?i)" + word, word.replaceAll(" ", "~"));
System.out.println(outText);
```

**Output:**

```
sony~ericsson is a leading company in mobile.
The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

---

### Avoid ruining the original capitalization:

In the above approach however, you're ruining the capitalization of the replaced word. Here is a better suggestion:

```
String inText="Sony Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. " +
              "The company sony ericsson was found in oct 2001";
String word = "sony ericsson";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inText);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
  String replacement = m.group().replace(' ', '~');
  m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String outText = sb.toString();

System.out.println(outText);
```

**Output:**

```
Sony~Ericsson is a leading company in mobile.
The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

Comment: @ajoobe: Awesome! how do I thank you buddy?

Answer (score 3):

`str.replaceAll(regex, repl)` [is equal to](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`. Thus, you can make your matcher case-insensitive with a [flag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

**Using backreferences to preserve case:**

```
Pattern.compile("(sony) (ericsson)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
       .matcher(str)
       .replaceAll("$1~$2")
```

Gives:

> Sony~Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. The company sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001

Comment: That's an elegant solution! However, it becomes trickier to use if the `word` variable is actually an argument to a function.

Comment: @aioobe Thank you. And yes, you're right; in order for this to work, the string to match (`"sony ericcson"`) must be known so that groups can be defined (`"(sony) (ericsson)"`). That would be tricky (at best!) if `"sony ericcson"` came from "the outside" (e.g., an external argument to a function).

Answer (score 0):

```
String outText = inText.replaceAll("(?i)(Sony) (Ericsson)", "$1~$2");
```

**Output**:

```
Sony~Ericsson is a leading company in mobile. The company Sony~ericsson was found in oct 2001
```

Comment: Thank you John for your suggestion