# Regex - search a word and replace it with same word using Case INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, string, search, replace, case-insensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regex replace all ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568081/regex-replace-all-ignore-case)

How do I get the required output?

input string -

```
"Software Industry. software Industry. SOFTWARE INDUSTRY. software industry. "
```

word to be searched -

```
"software industry"
```

Output -

```
"*Software Industry*. *software Industry*. *SOFTWARE INDUSTRY*. *software industry*. "
```

In short I have to find a phrase and replace the same phrase with starting and ending asterisk (*), IGNORING THE CASE ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with `(?i)` which will do `case-insensitive` replace.

```
String str = "Software Industry. software Industry. SOFTWARE INDUSTRY. "+
                                                    "software industry. "
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)(software industry)", "\\*$1\\*");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pattern Matching (Regex)for this.

First extract the phrase using group and store in string or any other data structure.
then use Replace function to achieve your output.

you can refer this post : http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also try something like:

```
String str=new String("Software Industry. software Industry. SOFTWARE INDUSTRY. software industry.");
str=Pattern.compile("(software industry)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str).replaceAll("*$1*");
```