# Java replace string sequences ignoring case?

Tags: java, string, replace, compare, pattern-matching

For a project, I've given a sequence that the program searches for and tries to find a sequence of letters. If it finds any, it makes those sequences capitalized and prints out the line.

For instance in sequence `bcdaaab` when I run the program, and specify the string `aa` as what to find,

what should be printed is: `bcdAAAb`
what is being printied is: `bcdAAab` (notice the third `a` is not capped).

This is because I'm just using the `replaceAll` function for strings which does not ignore case. I want to know if there is any way to make it so it ignores case when I'm searching. If I can't use `replaceAll` at all, could someone suggest other algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex replace all ignore case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568081/regex-replace-all-ignore-case)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that even with case-insensitive matching, it replaces the first 'aa' and then searches for the next match starting after the original replacement. Since the next position after the replacement is a single 'a' followed by a different letter, it doesn't consider it a match.

This will take care of your problem:

`"bcdaaab".replaceAll("(?i)a((?=a)|(?<=a))","A");`

Instead of replacing 'aa' with 'AA', use this to replace one 'a' at a time. It utilizes a lookahead and a lookbehind to basically say "is there another 'a' next to me?"

---

If you don't want to do that for whatever reason, you can always do a `while(matcher.find(offset))` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
String abc ="NewDc";
System.out.println(abc.replaceAll("(?i)dc"," Data Center."));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String s1 = "bcdaaab";
String s2 = "aa";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);

for (int i = 0;; i++) {
    i = s1.indexOf(s2, i);
    if (i == -1) {
        break;
    }
    sb.replace(i, i + s2.length(), s2.toUpperCase());
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

output

```
bcdAAAb
```

---

In case for replacement `aA` result also should be `bcdAAAb` you can use

```
String s1 = "bcdaaab";
String s2 = "aA".toUpperCase();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);
s1 = s1.toUpperCase();

for (int i = 0;; i++) {
    i = s1.indexOf(s2, i);
    if (i == -1) {
        break;
    }
    sb.replace(i, i + s2.length(), s2.toUpperCase());
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't ignore case, so for `aA` it will not work. Also you are nor using `s3` anywhere. Maybe you should add `s2 = s2.toUpperCase();` right after `s2` declaration and `i = s3.indexOf(s2, i);` inside loop?

Comment: Anyway +1 for nice and short answer since it can be easily corrected or in case I didn't understand OP requirements will not need correction :)

Comment: You are right, removed s3, and I am also not quite sure about requirements

Comment: I added updated version of your code to ignore case in replacement part. Hope you don't mind.